# hyperref: How to open a directory view with href{...}?

Tags: hyperref, links

I wrote a small LaTeX file which describes the contents of some directories.

Now I try to provide a direct link to the described files and directories. I successfully use `\href{filename.ext}{Link name}` to provide a link for files. Unfortunately if I pass a directory name to `\href` the PDF reader (tried with Adobe Reader and Evince) doesn't recognize the link.

Examples of unrecognized links (a directory named *abc* exists in the same directory as the .pdf is):

```
\href{abc}{Open abc directory}
\href{abc/}{Open abc directory}
\href{./abc}{Open abc directory}
\href{./abc/}{Open abc directory}
\href{run:abc}{Open abc directory}
\href{run:abc/}{Open abc directory}
\href{run:./abc}{Open abc directory}
\href{run:./abc/}{Open abc directory}
```

Does anyone know if there is any chance to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The root of the problem is that hyperref tries to be smart.  If no file extension is found, hyperref adds `.pdf`, so the link becomes either `abc.pdf` or `abc/.pdf` depending on whether there is trailing `/` in the call.

You can define your own command, say, `\HREF`, which simply constructs the link and does not do anything else.

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\HREF[2]{\hyper@linkurl{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\HREF{tmp}{open directory \texttt{tmp}}
\end{document}
```

Note that this works in `xpdf`.  Acrobat disables such links by security reasons.  `evince` works with absolute paths (`file:///home/boris/scratch`) but balks at relative ones: somehow `../tmp/` works, but `./tmp` does not.  I guess this is some bug in `evince`.

Answer (score 7):

As Boris said in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36613/50960), `.pdf` is appended if no extension is found.

To avoid this, use `\href{abc/.}{Open directory}`. The `.` (current directory) looks like a file extension.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a network folder, you can give the absolute path with

```
\href{run:/serverpath}
```

or

```
\href{run:///serverpath}
```

For example

```
\href{run:///192.198.1.5/data}{Network Folder}
```

If it's a local folder, you can give the absolute path with

```
\href{run://FolderPathOnC:Drive}
```

For example

```
\href{run://Users/Name/Downloads}{My Downloads Folder}
```

Tested with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 2020.009.20065.