# How do I create an link to a folder?

Tags: formatting, hyperref, folders

I am trying to create a link to a folder such as

C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip

I have tried to use href, but as I understand that automatically appends a .pdf to the end.

I tried the solution in [hyperref: How to open a directory view with href{...}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36567/hyperref-how-to-open-a-directory-view-with-href)

but no success there either. The documentation http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html seems to imply that \url{} can be used for paths. But this just generated a text version of the url.

What is the correct method for linking to a folder? Am I misusing a method or am I not using the correct approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Please post the code you have tried.  Loading `hyperref` and using `\url` should work, but will display the path name in the file too.  What end result do you want?

Comment: If you give a pathname to MS internet explorer, it will display the directory, but this is not standard behavior.  The first thing it should do is look for `home.html` or `index.html`.  Firefox defaults to using the search engine.

Answer (score 6):

For local paths:

```
\href{file:C:/foo/bar/baz/.}
```

The trailing period looks like a file extension so hyperref doesn't try to be smart and append ".pdf".

For UNC paths you need to double the leading forward-slashes for some reason:

```
\href{file:////server/share/foo/bar/baz/.}
```

There's no need to slash-escape embedded space characters in the path.

I haven't been able to get the usually-recommended \href{run:.......} syntax working for directories.

Tested on MikTeX (via Sweave) in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

On MacOS, the MWE below produces:

[image]

and upon clicking on the link it invokes `Finder` and opens to the `../images` directory.

### Notes:

- Only relative links work. Absolute directory paths do not seem to work.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \href{run:../images}{My Images Folder}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a network folder, you can give the absolute path with

```
\href{run:/serverpath}
```

or

```
\href{run:///serverpath}
```

For example

```
\href{run:///192.198.1.5/data}{Network Folder}
```

If it's a local folder, you can give the absolute path with

```
\href{run://FolderPathOnC:Drive}
```

For example

```
\href{run://Users/Name/Downloads}{My Downloads Folder}
```

Tested with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Version 2020.009.20065.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but it does show some of my experiments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{C:/Program Files (x86)/7-Zip}% replace \ with /

\href{../slides/demo}{pdf}% relative pathname

\href{../slides}{directory}% does nothing

\href{../slides/}{directory}% does nothing
\end{document}
```